# how to show central point in stat_ellipse in ggplot2

Tags: r, ggplot2

how can ggplot2 show the central point in stat_ellipse?
or in other way, how to caculated coordinate of this point according to related matrix(2 column)?

I dont know if it can be done in ggplot2, or only can caculated this point beforehand.

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't understand why you want the central point, but does this solve your problem?

```r
library(tidyverse)

ggplot(faithful, aes(waiting, eruptions)) +
  geom_point() +
  stat_ellipse() +
  stat_ellipse(level = 0.0001, geom = "point", color = "red")
```

[image]

<sup>Created on 2023-02-14 with [reprex v2.0.2](https://reprex.tidyverse.org)</sup>

Comment: thank you. I just want to mark the distance line between two data sets(ellipse). I will try this code latter.